# NSPredicate how to filter object fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

How do I filter an array of objects by a specific field?

My code:

```
NSMutableArray *inputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
Person *person = [[Person alloc]init];
person.first_name = @"John";
[inputArray addObject: person];

person = [[Person alloc]init];
person.first_name = @"Jack";
[inputArray addObject: person];

NSString *expression = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(inputArray, $object, $object.first_name CONTAINS[c] J"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:expression];
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Count should be 2: %lu",(unsigned long)filteredArray.count);
```

This is the error I get:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "SUBQUERY(inputArray, $object, $object.first_name CONTAINS[c] J"'
```

This is a basic example for testing. The real-case scenario is that I have an array of objects (Person or whatever) and I want to filter that array by certain fields within the objects ie first_name.  As the user types we will filter a visual list based on what they type - so typing "J" would yield 2 results, but then when they type "Jo" only "John" appears on the list.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Still doesn't seem to be working. Updated code:

```
DOVisitor *vi = [inputArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"NAME: %@",vi.first_name);
NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_name LIKE[cd] %@", @"Jo"];
NSPredicate *lastNamePredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"last_name LIKE[cd] %@", @"Jo"];

NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates : @[firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate]];
NSArray *filteredArray = [[inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:finalPredicate]mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"Count should be 1: %d", [filteredArray count]);
```

I get an empty array back. However when I print the first object of the inputArray the console logs "John"

**EDIT**

Using CONTAINS instead of LIKE does the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for this, this is a very basic filter.

```
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"first_name CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"j"];
```

Comment: Dima this works well if we are filtering a first name OR a last name - but what if I want to filter for best match? Meaning - I have a textfield where the user types full name "John Smith". I will remove the whitespace character. Now I want to throw the string "JohnSmith" at the predicate. If we have a perfect match after comparing both last and first names then that is the one we want. My current code fails when the textfield hits the last name so "John S" returns 0 results.

Comment: I dont exactly understand the question. You should ask a new question with more details and the code you're trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say you have `Person` object and you are trying to search for both `firstName` and `lastName`, then you can use:

```
NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName LIKE[cd] %@", @"Jo"];
NSPredicate *lastNamePredicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lastName LIKE[cd] %@", @"Jo"];

NSPredicate *finalPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates : @[firstNamePredicate, lastNamePredicate]];
```

The final Predicate is generated by `or`ing the previous predicates. So even if `Jo` is present in `firstName` or `lastName`, that `Person` object will pass the predicate test.

#### Edit:

Get filtered objects with above predicate

```
NSArray *filteredArray = [inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:finalPredicate];
```

Comment: But I don't want a filtered array of string names - I want to get a filtered array of my objects? Are you saying that if I just use the Person.first_name as part of the predicate that it will pull that field from my object automatically? Does that make sense? So lets say I have 10 Person objects in an array - are you saying that if I run this code of yours against that array of objects it will return me a list of objects that were filtered by the first_name property?

Comment: @Spentak, exactly, it will filter the array of `Person`s based on that predicate

Comment: Looks like "LIKE" is the problem. When I do CONTAINS it works